# Android FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE giving error

Tags: android

I have the following code which results in error message that I *can not combine FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE with other title features* (which I am not to my knowledge...)

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

String customTitleStr = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Title");

Boolean customTitleSupported = this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

if ( (customTitleSupported) && (customTitleStr != null) ) {
  getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.override_titlebar);
  final TextView myTitleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTitleText);
  if ( myTitleText != null ) {
      myTitleText.setText(customTitleStr);
  }                  
}
```

I have tried place **setContentView(R.layout.);** both before and after **this.requestWindowFeature** but no change.

My manifest targets this:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"                
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" 
  />
```

For reference (don't know if related), I also have trouble theming my titlebar. (Simply ignored.)

Just in case it is relevant, some code snippets for my theming:

*AndroidManifest.xml:*

```
  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/replace__logo__app_android"
    android:label="@string/MicAppName"
    android:theme="@style/MicTheme"
    android:name="com.examples.example.MicApp"    
  >
```

*styles.xml:*

```
   <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
   </style>

   <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
   </style>

   // ...

   <style name="MicTheme" parent="AppTheme">
     <item name="android:windowTitleSize">44dip</item>
     <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/MicWindowTitleBackground</item>
     <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/MicWindowTitle</item>     
   </style>
```

Comment: Add theme property for the activity in your AndroidManfiest.xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with this code.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;

public class CustomTitleBar extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.mytitle);

    }
}
```

for more information about how to set custom title bar please follow below tutorials.

http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-programming-tutorials/creating-a-custom-title-bar/

http://www.powenko.com/en/?p=214

http://7thursdays.wordpress.com/2012/10/14/how-to-make-a-custom-title-with-android/
hope this helps you.

**EDIT**
here is the working screenshot.

[image]

Comment: hi i have tested in emulator its working fine. i am followed the below tutorial http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-programming-tutorials/creating-a-custom-title-bar/

Comment: I will check the references on a fresh project incase something on my own project is causing problems. I have been testing on SG2. (Just a quick note: I have not cast the negative vote. I appreciate all efforts in helping me. I will come back after have read the references and uplciated them on a fresh project.)

Comment: Okay. I don't know what to say or do. I can get the demo working, but if I duplicate the code into my own project, I still get the error. I am out of ideas for now. Thanks though! :(

Comment: I am actually making a little progress. I have splut up my styles.xml into multiple files split across "values" and "values-11". In "values-11" I now have defined my style with **<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item><item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>** Now I can see the styles (colors etc.) if I set it for entire app AndroidManifest.xml - if I only set it for the activity, it still does not work. I will continue poke with this since, well, I am still far from getting all working.

Comment: Okay. Well, further ttinkering, and everything now works. The error I got was supposedly all along because the action bar was enabled. From there, I could get rest working. The demo however helped convince me it was possible. Thanks :)